# Return data if no data exists - populate nulls with data

Tags: t-sql, null, common-table-expression

I've created a query and i would like to results to look like as follows:

```
Reporting Date    Fund    AssetClass    %
31/10/2012        1       Equity        10
31/10/2012        1       Bond          40
31/10/2012        1       Cash          40
31/10/2012        1       Balanced      10
31/10/2012        1       Other         0
```

The problem i'm having above is where the % is 0 and it obviously not showing as there is no data.  However i would like it to show.

So i thought the best solution would be to create a temp table with all the Asset Classes in it and then RIGHT OUTER JOIN to it from my worktable so that it would populate a line with no data.  The code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    ReportingDate
,   PortfolioID
,   AC.AssetClass
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC) AS [Rank]
,   CAST(SUM(Percentage) AS DECIMAL(22,1))  AS [Weight]

FROM @Worktable as WT

RIGHT OUTER JOIN @AssetClass AS AC
    ON WT.AssetClass = AC.AssetClass

GROUP BY WT.ReportingDate, WT.PortfolioID, AC.AssetClass

ORDER BY [Weight] DESC
```

My problem is that when this returns it looks like this:

```
Reporting Date    Fund    AssetClass    %
31/10/2012        1       Equity        10
31/10/2012        1       Bond          40
31/10/2012        1       Cash          40
31/10/2012        1       Balanced      10
NULL              NULL    Other         NULL
```

How can i populate the NULL's with data in this script?  Is there potentially another better way of doing this?

Comment: could you not just use ISNULL in the select query? For example ISNULL(PortfolioID, 0)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: what happens when you use it?

Comment: It returns a null like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Reporting IS NULL THEN MAX(Reporting) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT 1)) ELSE Reporting END AS Reporting
,   CASE WHEN Fund IS NULL THEN MAX(Fund) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT 1)) ELSE Fund END AS Fund
,   PortfolioID
,   AC.AssetClass
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC) AS [Rank]
,   CAST(SUM(ISNULL(Percentage, 0)) AS DECIMAL(22,1))  AS [Weight]
FROM @Worktable as WT
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @AssetClass AS AC
    ON WT.AssetClass = AC.AssetClass
GROUP BY WT.ReportingDate, WT.PortfolioID, AC.AssetClass
ORDER BY [Weight] DESC
```